# Searching through pdf files on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I upload documents on SharePoint list and i could search their contents in case they are .doc or .txt files. However, search results do not include files of type .pdf or .docx
Is there something to include or add? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharepoint uses [IFilter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFilter) plugins to search the contents of non-trivial and non-Office files. Try installing [the Adobe PDF IFilter](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=2611). There's also [documentation](http://www.adobe.com/special/acrobat/configuring_pdf_ifilter_for_ms_sharepoint_2007.pdf) explaining how to configure it.

Comment: I was not able to find the path in the registry which was mentioned in the document! Any clue?

Comment: The document mentions several registry paths. Which one did you not find?

Comment: I found them now. At first, I didn't install the version for x64 bit and I still had to enable searching in SharePoint. Now, I did what's mentioned but still I couldn't get the results. I guess I'll repeat it again, thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint uses Ifilter for indexing the content of any type of document uploaded to the SharePoint. for office products like word, excel powerpoint the filter is provided with the installation for any other document types like PDF, Zip, tiff user would have to install the respective ifilter for PDF documents the latest ifilter can be downloaded from the adobe site after the installation of ifilter you would be required to add the file  extension in file types in your ssp search setting